# Elementary Separable Differential Equation with tricky integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is to solve the separable differential equation
 $\sqrt{xy}~~\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{4-x}$.

My work thus far: 
 $    \sqrt{xy}~~ {dy}=\sqrt{4-x}~~dx 
\\  \sqrt{y}~~ {dy}=\sqrt{\frac{4-x}{x}}~~dx 
\\  \int \sqrt{y}~~ {dy}= \int \sqrt{\frac{4-x}{x}}~~d x
\\ \frac{2}{3} y^{3/2} =\int \sqrt{\frac{4-x}{x}}~~dx
\\ \frac{2}{3} y^{3/2} =\int \sqrt{\frac 4 x - 1 }~~dx
 $

The right side is a difficult integral to evaluate.

Is there an easier approach I have missed, or should I persist in trying to solve the integral.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Apply the substitution $u=\frac{4}{x}$, then integrate by parts and then again look for a clever substitution to get to the form $\int\frac{1}{t^2+1}dt=arctan(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Sometimes an integral $\int \sqrt{f(x)} \, dx$ can be resolved by rearranging $u = \sqrt{f(x)}$ to give a reverse substitution (where we may need to restrict the domain of $f$).

In our case, setting $u = \sqrt\frac{4 - x}{x}$ and rearranging and differentiating yields the substitution
$$x = \frac{4}{u^2 + 1}, \qquad dx = -\frac{8 u\, du}{(u^2 + 1)^2},$$
which gives
$$\int \sqrt\frac{4 - x}{x} dx = -8 \int \frac{u^2 \,du}{(u^2 + 1)^2} .$$
The latter integrand is rational and so can be solved with standard techniques.

> The occurrence of the form $u^2 + 1$ in the denominator suggests the substitution $u = \tan \theta$, $du = \sec^2 \theta\, d\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

Make the substitution $t = \sqrt{x}$, then

$$ \int 2\sqrt{4-x}\ \frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x}} = \int 2\sqrt{4-t^2}\ dt $$

This is a standard trig substitution. Let $t = 2\sin \theta$

\begin{align} 
\int 2\sqrt{4-t^2}dt &= \int 2\cdot 2\cos\theta\cdot 2\cos\theta\ d\theta \\ 
&= \int 8 \cos^2\theta\ d\theta \\
&= \int 4(1+\cos2\theta)\ d\theta \\
&= 4\theta + 2\sin2\theta + C 
\end{align}

Going backwards

\begin{align} 
4\theta + 2\sin2\theta + C &= 4\theta + 4\sin\theta\cos \theta + C \\
&= 4\arctan\frac{t}{2} + t\sqrt{4-t^2} + C \\
&= 4\arcsin\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2} + \sqrt{x}\sqrt{4-x} + C
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**Thankyou** to the tips given. I will attempt to answer my question. 
$$  \sqrt{xy}~~\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{4-x} 
\\  \sqrt{xy}~~ {dy}=\sqrt{4-x}~~dx 
\\  \sqrt{y}~~ {dy}=\sqrt{\frac{4-x}{x}}~~dx
\\  \int \sqrt{y}~~ {dy}= \int \frac{ \sqrt {4-x}}{\sqrt x}~~dx 
\\ \frac{2}{3} y^{3/2} =\int \frac{ \sqrt {4-x}}{\sqrt x}~~dx 
\\ \text{ Make the substitution u = √x  }
 \\  \frac{2}{3} y^{3/2} = 2\int  \sqrt { 4- u^2} du 
\\ \\ \text{ Substitute w = u/2 }
 \\  \frac{2}{3} y^{3/2} =  8  \int  \sqrt{  1 - w  ^2} ~dw  
\\ \text{ using trig substitution}
\\  \frac{2}{3} y^{3/2} =  4 w \sqrt {1 -w^2}+4 \arcsin \left( w \right) + C
\\ \text{back substituting }
 \\ \frac{2}{3} y^{3/2} =  4 \frac u 2  \sqrt {1 -\left( \frac u 2  \right) ^2}+4 \arcsin \left( \frac u 2  \right) + C 
\\ \frac{2}{3} y^{3/2} =   2 \sqrt x    \sqrt {1 -\left( \frac {\sqrt x }{ 2}  \right) ^2}+4 \arcsin \left( \frac {\sqrt x }{ 2}  \right) + C 
\\ \frac{2}{3} y^{3/2} =   2 \sqrt x    \sqrt {1 -\left( \frac {x}{4}  \right)}+4 \arcsin \left( \frac {\sqrt x }{ 2}  \right) + C 
\\ \frac{2}{3} y^{3/2} =   2 \sqrt x   \frac{ \sqrt {4 -x }}{ \sqrt{4} } +4 \arcsin \left( \frac {\sqrt x }{ 2}  \right) + C 
\\ \frac{2}{3} y^{3/2} =    \sqrt x  \sqrt {4 -x }  +4 \arcsin \left( \frac {\sqrt x }{ 2}  \right) + C 
\\  y^{3/2} =\frac{3}{2}  \left(   \sqrt x  \sqrt {4 -x }  +4 \arcsin \left( \frac {\sqrt x }{ 2}  \right) + C \right)
\\  y^{3/2} = \left( \frac{3}{2} \sqrt x  \sqrt {4 -x }  + 6 \arcsin \left( \frac {\sqrt x }{ 2}  \right) + \frac 3 2 C \right)
\\  y = \left( \frac{3}{2} \sqrt x  \sqrt {4 -x }  + 6 \arcsin \left( \frac {\sqrt x }{ 2}  \right) + C \right) ^{2/3}$$